# Python Axon Binary File

Tags: python, mingw

I would like to read Axon Binary File (ABF) in python; I found this http://www.stimfit.org/doc/sphinx/stfio/index.html but the building instructions are only for Linux... at the moment I am using Windows and pythonxy distribution. Can someone help me to understand how to build only stfio library with mingw32 and python? :)

Thanks a lot for any help

Answer (score 2):

The [google code page](https://code.google.com/p/stimfit/) of the module you are linking has [windows installer files](https://code.google.com/p/stimfit/downloads/list) available.

Comment: I tryed but it didn't work, I must copy some dlls and stfio python script from installation directory in my project and when I try to use .asarray() method like http://www.stimfit.org/doc/sphinx/stfio/index.html the program stop to work (like in infinite loop)

Comment: Fixed, instead of .asarray() it is possible to use np.array(...) but it is very slow... are there other modules to read abf file?